# Breadcrumb designed with ant to not be shown dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I used breadcrumbs related to ant design in my design.
I am currently using Ant Design version 5.12.2
Considering that the use of Breadcrumb.Item is deprecated in version 5.3.0 and later, I want to use itmes property.
This code does not show any error, but unfortunately, it does not display anything on the page either.
I can't figure out which part of the code is wrong, it doesn't show any error, nor the content inside the ol tag.
Thank you for helping me.
[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


import { WrapperHeader } from './WrapperHeader.styled';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Breadcrumb } from 'antd';
import { useGetProfileInfoQuery } from '@services/dashboardApi';

const Header = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const Navigate = useNavigate();
  const { data: getProfileInfo } = useGetProfileInfoQuery();
  const pathSnippets = location.pathname.split('/').filter((item) => item);


  const breadcrumbNameMap: Record<string, string> = {
    '/dashboard': 'Dashboard',
    '/dashboard/add_new_property': 'Adding New Property',
    '/properties': 'Properties',
    '/investments': 'Investments',
    '/opportunities': 'Opportunities',
    '/opportunities/investing': 'Investing',
    '/transaction_records': 'Transaction Records',
    '/profile': 'Profile Management',
    '/profile/privacy_policy': 'Privacy Policy',
    '/profile/terms_conditions': 'Terms Conditions',
    '/profile/help_center': 'Help Center',
  };

  const breadcrumbItems = pathSnippets.length > 0 ? pathSnippets.map((_, index) => {
    const url = `/${pathSnippets.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')}`;
    console.log('url :>> ', url);
    return {
      key: url,
      ...(index !== pathSnippets.length - 1
        ? { element: <Link to={url}>{breadcrumbNameMap[url]}</Link> }
        : { content: breadcrumbNameMap[url] }),
    };
  }): undefined;

  return (
    <WrapperHeader>
      <Breadcrumb separator="/" items={breadcrumbItems} />

      
      {/* <Breadcrumb separator="/">
        {pathSnippets.length > 0 &&
          pathSnippets.map((_, index) => {
            const url = `/${pathSnippets.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')}`;
            return (
              <Breadcrumb.Item key={url}>
                {index !== pathSnippets.length - 1 ? (
                  <Link to={url}>{breadcrumbNameMap[url]}</Link>
                ) : (
                  <span>{breadcrumbNameMap[url]}</span>
                )}
              </Breadcrumb.Item>
            );
          })}
      </Breadcrumb> */}

    </WrapperHeader>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

hich part of the code is wrong, it doesn't show any error, nor the content inside the ol tag.
Thank you for helping me